# cannot extract links with beautifulsoup4 on dirrectmirror web page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract links from specific web page like:
http://www.directmirror.com/files/0GR7ZPCY

but it doesn't work as the example in bs4's document. Can anyone point out the reason for me? My code is as following:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.directmirror.com/files/0GR7ZPCY')
html = response.read()
sp = BeautifulSoup(html)
ll = sp.find_all('a')
```

The 'll' variable I got is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** The problem appeared to be with Ubuntu's installation of BS4 - uninstalling and reinstalling with pip solved the problem

---

This actually works for me using both cases (`find_all` for BS4 and and the older `findAll`). Have you verified that you have content in your `sp` variable?

```
In [1]: import urllib2

In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [3]: response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.directmirror.com/files/0GR7ZPCY')

In [4]: html = response.read()

In [5]: sp = BeautifulSoup(html)

In [6]: ll = sp.find_all('a')

In [7]: ll
Out[7]:
[<a class="twitter-share-button" data-count="vertical" data-via="DirectMirror" href="http://twitter.com/share">Tweet</a>,
 <a href="/"><img alt="logo" border="0" src="/images/logo2.png"/></a>,
 <a href="/register.php" style="color:#ffffff">Register</a>,
 <a href="/login.php" style="color:#ffffff">Login</a>,
 # Continues...
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I do verify I have content of the 'html' variable. I tried a random page of other website and the code looked ok. It's a little bit weird.

Comment: @VeryelHua Have you tried changing `find_all` to `findAll`? That was the old BeautifulSoup method name, but it may work (`find_all` returned nothing initially, but switching to `findAll` worked - however then `find_all` worked again. Go figure :) ).

Comment: I tried findAll. But I still get an empty list. Can you offer some approaches to identify the reason? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I found I can also get it work on my laptop. But it doesn't work on the server I used.

Comment: @VeryelHua Hmm, have you tried it with other tags? For instance, does `find_all('li')` return any list items?

Comment: I found it might be the problem of ubuntu's binary bs4 package. Since I remove the existing one and re-installed it with pip, it's ok. Thank you!

Comment: @VeryelHua Ha, well glad you got it sorted out - enjoy the soup!